# Add dimensions with mod coder pack Minecraft

Tags: java, eclipse, minecraft

I am trying to add my own dimension into Minecraft using only its code (No outside programs, mod, plugins, etc.) And I am having troubles doing this. I have created my dimension, and it works fine, I can get to it by replacing an existing one (tested with the nether, worked fine), however I cannot seem to find out how to add the dimension without replacing an existing dimension. After some testing, I believe there is a limit of 3 dimensions somewhere, these dimensions being the overworld, end, and nether. I can't imagine that there wouldn't be a way to add another dimension, since if it was decided to add another dimension, this exact thing would need to be done, my question is: How do I add another dimension without replacing an existing one? And: If my theory that there is a limit, where is the location of the limit (what is the name of the class file?)

I created a Minecraft forum post on this issue, I would paste that information here but it felt neater for me to link it instead:

http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/mapping-and-modding/minecraft-mods/modification-development/2856901-minecraft-mod-coder-pack-adding-a-dimension

Most important information from there has already been put here anyhow. Thank you for reading and any potential help!

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution, the class files that need to be edited are: AnvilSaveHandler, IntegratedServer (for client), DimensionType, MinecraftServer (for a server), and I believe this should be it. Possibly AnvilSaveConverter, but I doubt that.